# Keyboard Map Binding

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm having some trouble coming up with a xaml page that would bind to a keyboard layout displayed on a page.  Originally I have an ObservableCollection of rows that contain a KeyboardKey datatypes that specify the width of a button.  The collection is bound to a listbox in the xaml.  The problem I'm having is that on some keyboards the the height of a key spans two rows, which the xaml listbox does not support.  I would like to avoid hard coding a bunch of keys in the xaml.  Any thoughts on how to approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create you own layout buy inheriting one of container controls and overriding
ArrangeOverride method.

You can find the example here: http://www.wpftutorial.net/CustomLayoutPanel.html

When I was creating the virtual keyboard, I declined automatic layout and put the buttons manually in designer. I think in some cultures it is better to put key rows with horizontal shift and in others it is better to to place buttons under each other. So I have a flexible layout and can quickly edit it in designer.